# Analysing the result of jmeter load testing using HTML report Dashboard

Tags: csv, jmeter, report, load-testing

I am analyzing the test results for jmeter using HTML Report Dashboard, but it displays the output of just one particular time but not for all samples

I have tried looking for solutions online, but couldnt find any

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your load test lasts 1 minute (which is not meaningful anyway),since you're using 1min granularity you end up with 1 point.

So:

- Either increase test duration
- Change in user.properties:

> jmeter.reportgenerator.overall_granularity=1000

See:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#reporting

Read this [blog](https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/reporting-feature-in-jmeter/) for more details.

To learn more about performance testing and JMeter, this [book](https://leanpub.com/master-jmeter-from-load-test-to-devops) can help you.